# My service that I injected with DI has many methods. Is there a way that I can make these easy to locate?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection version 5.0.1 nuget package

Here's an example.  It's a UtilityService with a large number (over 100) methods:

```
public partial class UtilsService : IUtilsService
{

    private IDatabaseService _databaseService;
    private IConfigService _configService;

    public UtilsService(IDatabaseService databaseService, IConfigService configService)
    {
        _databaseService = databaseService;
        _configService = configService;
    }

    public delegate void OnCompleteCallBack(object result, bool status);

    public string SetTimeHeader(TIME setting)
    {
        ///
    }

    public string SetTimeBack()
    {
        ///
    }

    public async Task PopulateMetrics()
    {
        ///
    }
```

The methods can be divided up into different groups such as:

```
Time utilities
Statistics utilities
View utilities
....
```

I realize I could just keep on creating more and more services for each of these but by doing that my application will end up with very many services that just have utility methods.

Is there some way that I can have one UtilityService and then have these methods grouped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create multiple utility interfaces:

```
ITimeUtilities
IStatisticstilities
IViewtilities
```

and implement like this:

```
public partial class UtilsService : ITimeUtilities, IStatisticstilities, IViewtilities
```

Then you can inject the appropriate interface to whoever needs it by using the same concrete class.

You can also declare the interface as:

```
public interface IUtilsService : ITimeUtilities, IStatisticstilities, IViewtilities
```

Utitly classes are a bad habit though and possibly a code smell. They violate the single responsibility principle with low cohesion and readability as well.

I do recommend that you create many services as they cost nothing, they are discoverable and group cohesive functions as well.

In case you need them elsewhere (other project) you can very easily get them there.